# www domain and the main domain has different layout

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare, godaddy-api

I buy a domain name from Godaddy, replace nameservers with Cloudflare, and point DNS to my host on Hostinger.

On Hostinger, I set the OS to Unbuntu with WordPress. I configured my site with an SSH key on the local terminal to proceed with the WordPress Installation. After everything is done, my site can be viewed perfectly with the domain name.
I deploy my local site on LocalWP to the host using the All in One WP Migration plugin. Everything was ok until I accessed [www.example123.com](http://www.example123.com). My site showed the layout before I deployed.

I thought it was a subdomain, so I tried to access /wp-admin/, but it redirected to mydomain.com/wp-admin/. I checked again on GoDaddy to see if I had created any subdomains, but nothing was found. The only WWW part that I found is in the CloudFlare. But it did not relate anything to my site.

Can anybody help what is going on with my site? I seriously don't understand anything of this.

(I am a non-coder also, literally know little about code)

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few [almost] non-technical solutions that you can follow:

#### 1- Check WordPress address and site address.

Go to WordPress admin dashboard and navigate to Settings > General. Make sure **WordPress address** and **site address** fields are set correctly. They must match the domain you want to use(test.com) and not the WWW subdomain.

#### 2- Find website redirects in .htaccess file.

It's possible that there is a redirect set up in your WordPress installation or in your hosting environment.

#### 3- Clear all caches.

If you are using a caching plugin or a caching service like Cloudflare, clear their caches. Also don't forget to clear your browser's cache.

#### 4- Check the DNS settings

Make sure that the DNS settings for both the main domain and the WWW subdomain are correctly configured. For this, you must log into your host/server control panel.

#### 5- Contact service support